# Tell if a series converges uniformly

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

> Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2}$. Check if $f_n(x)$ converges to a continuous function.

So I've seen a solution that uses the fact that if $f(x)$ converges uniformly and $f_n(x)$ are continuous, so does $f(x)$.

The author search for maximum points of $\frac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2}$. Afterward, he applied the two maximum points, $x_{M_1}, x_{M_2}$ for $f(x)$, and showed that $f(x)$ converges at those points.

He reached the conclusion that $f(x)$ converges uniformly.

What's the theorem behind that?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac x{x^2+n^2}=\pi\coth\pi x\qquad$ and $\qquad\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{2x^3}{(x^2+n^2)^2}=\pi\coth\pi x+\pi^2x~\text{csch}^2\pi x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author used the [Weierstrass M-test theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: Oh I see. He showed (in this case) that the maximal value is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ and this is indeed can be utilized for Weierstrass M-test theorem. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.